# Suggestions for VB.Net graphical context menu..?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can anyone offer a suggestion for creating a graphical context menu in VB.Net..?

I'm creating a small app with context menus that have become very long, and I would like to have them laid out in table format with icons instead of text. I could create a borderless popup form, but...I wonder if this is reinventing the wheel.

Are there any built-in .Net objects that might function as a graphical context menu, instead of the standard ContextMenuStrip..? I did look at creating a WPF app instead, but I think I'm not ready for that yet.

Here is an approximate example of what I'd like to do, but no borders or command buttons; only the icon grid. This is the image selector from the Quick Access Toolbar editor in Excel...

[image]

Comment: You can create a form without borders and caption.

Comment: Yes I understand, and I'm considering it. I was simply wondering if .Net has some sort of graphical menu class that I'm not aware of. The ContextMenuStrip might work if it could be configured to display in a table form instead of list, but it cannot.